# How to display grouped hierarchical data in ListBox

Tags: wpf

I have hierarchical data. I need to display this in a listbox grouped by each level. Test data for this looks like:

```
public class StudentAwardDisbursement {
  public string StudentName {get; set;}
  public int AwardTotal {get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<AwardDisbursement > {get; set;}
}

public class AwardDisbursement {
  public string AcademicYearHeader {get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<Disbursements > {get; set;}
}

public class Disbursements {
  public DateTime DisbursedOn {get; set;}
  public int DisbursedAmount {get; set;}
}
```

My best attempt so far looks like:

```
  <StackPanel x:Name="DisbursementsPanel">
     <StackPanel x:Name="StudentHeader">
        <TextBlock Text="All Disbursements for " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StudentName}" />
     </StackPanel>

     <ListBox x:Name="FinanicalAwardList" DataContext="{Binding AwardDisbursement}">
        <StackPanel>
           <TextBlock x:Name="FinancialAwardHeaderText" Text="{Binding AcademicYearHeader}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Disbursements}">
           <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="black" />
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                          <TextBlock Text="Disbursed On" />
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisbursedOn}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                          <TextBlock Text="Amount" Margin="0,6,0,0"/>
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisbursedAmount }"/>
                       </StackPanel>
                 </StackPanel>
              </DataTemplate>
           </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
     </ListBox>

     <StackPanel x:Name="StudentFooter" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="DarkGray">
        <TextBlock Text="Awards: " FontSize="14" Foreground="White" Padding="6,6,0,6"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AwardTotal, StringFormat=c0}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Padding="0,6,6,6"/>
     </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
```

This example also has a footer with an aggregated value for a student. The problem is that grouping is not taking place. I get only one "FinancialHeaderText". All the disbursments are displaying, but not grouped by "AcademicYearHeader". The needs of the display do not allow a treeview.  I've failed to make hierarchicaDataTemplate and CollectionViewSource work, stil a newbie I guess. I'm open to trying again with sufficient hints and examples. This is a readonly display if that helps any. Suggestions?

Comment: You mentioned that you failed to get "hierarchicaDataTemplate" to work.  What part(s) are causing troubles?

Comment: I couldn't find an example of applying it to a listbox that I could understand.

Comment: I don't know of the best way to approach this problem. TreeView is out cause the customer want's it to look like their existing form. That's why I got stuck on using a listbox and stackpanels. I shaped the data into nested ObservableCollections and then got blocked by how to present the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout is perceived by XAML as this:

```
< StudentHeader >
    < ListBox: StudentAwardDisbursement.AwardDisbursements >
       < Item1: AcademicYearHeader >
       < Item2: AwardDisbursement.Disbursements > (ListBox)
          < AwardDisbursement 0 >
          < AwardDisbursement 1 >
                   ...
          < AwardDisbursement N >
```

The error is in your 1st ListBox, Item1 and Item2.  It should be more like:

```
< StudentHeader >
    < ListBox: StudentAwardDisbursement.AwardDisbursements >
       < ListBox.ItemTemplate > *** Inside ItemTemplate ***          
          < AcademicYearHeader >
          < ListBox AwardDisbursement.Disbursements >
             < ListBox.ItemTemplate >   
                < DataTemplate Disbursement >
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried that, but < ListBox AwardDisbursement.disbursements > makes use of an ItemTemplate. WPF prevents me from defining another ItemTemplate at the parent level. This is when I started searching for alternate ways to display hierarchical data.

Comment: Another error was explicitly setting 1st `ListBox`'s `DataContext`.  It's `ItemsSource` needs to be set and **NOT** `DataContext`.

Comment: I'll leave the complete solution as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thanks again. I've got it working with a treeview opening up to the listbox I want, so I'm ready for Monday. I'll try your solution tomorrow. It seems so simple when _you_ say it like that.

Comment: I know, I know. Sorry now, but I'm trying to help you learn. ;)  A tip: usually, `DataContext` is only set once and to the _root_ element (rarely in elements lower in the tree).